# Teste de mesa - baseado em opinião?

Tags: debate

Uma pergunta sobre os passos para realizar um teste de mesa seria uma pergunta baseada em opinião?

Pergunto isso porque muitas perguntas básicas com erros em lógica que aqui são postadas poderiam ser facilmente resolvidas se o autor realizar o teste de mesa e identificar o erro na lógica. Acredito que, na maioria, são essas perguntas que acabam deixando o SOpt com ar de fórum de suporte, pois uma resposta a uma pergunta deste tipo interessa quase que unicamente ao autor da pergunta e não à comunidade em si. Procurando alguma pergunta relacionada a isso, encontrei apenas:

- [Teste de Mesa em vetor Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119975/5878)
- [Como fazer Teste de Mesa para determinado algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136393/como-fazer-teste-de-mesa-para-determinado-algoritmo)

Na segunda pergunta, inclusive, consta com a resposta aceita iniciando-se com "Cada um adota uma técnica própria de fazer o teste de mesa" e é basicamente esse é o meu receio de se configurar uma pergunta baseada em opinião.

Analisando a pergunta [O que é uma pergunta baseada em opiniões?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-pergunta-baseada-em-opini%C3%B5es) acredito que seria possível gerar uma pergunta neste sentido de modo a gerar uma, ou várias, resposta que mostra um método de realizar o teste de mesa sem depender apenas da preferência pessoal.

Particularmente eu já utilizei testes de mesa para auxiliar nas respostas e acho que foram úteis de certa forma.

- [Retornar todos os aniversariantes do mês escolhido pelo usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205207/retornar-todos-os-aniversariantes-do-m%C3%AAs-escolhido-pelo-usu%C3%A1rio/205223#205223)
- [Recursão - Desejo contar quantas vezes os algarismos 3 e 4 aparecem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204864/recurs%C3%A3o-desejo-contar-quantas-vezes-os-algarismos-3-e-4-aparecem/204868#204868)

O que acham? Seria possível/útil ter alguma orientação sobre isso no SOpt e será que é possível descrever de forma um tanto quanto genérica os passos para realizar um teste de mesa?

Comment: Não acho que "teste de mesa" seja baseado em opiniões. Na verdade qualquer pergunta pode ser baseada em opiniões dependendo da forma que foi elaborada. Mesmo sabendo que cada um pode adotar uma técnica para fazer teste de mesa, ainda é possível responder sem dar uma opinião, já que o resultado que se deseja alcançar é um só.

Comment: Concordo @gato!

Comment: O que é "teste de mesa"?

Comment: Não sei qual a definição formal, mas conheço teste de mesa como um método de analisar o funcionamento do código com papel e caneta, onde você vai acompanhando a execução linha a linha, anotando os valores das variáveis e verificando se está de acordo com o esperado.

Comment: fiquei curioso agora para saber como vocês chamam, @Sergio :)

Comment: Hum, se você fizer uma pergunta-respondida sobre qualquer técnica de debug, provavelmente isso não evitará que as "perguntas de fórum" parem de ser feitas e acho improvável que diminuam. Mas pode ser útil, se num comentário ou resposta a essas perguntas você colocar um link para a pergunta-respondida que explica a técnica de debug adequada para solucionar o problema do AP. Assim você ensina a pescar além (ou ao invés) de dar o peixe :)

Comment: @Douglas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878

Comment: @Sergio e quem não estiver familiarizado com o termo "Teste de Mesa", esse método de depuração aqui debatido também é conhecido como "Trace Table".

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Respondendo basicamente para não deixar o assunto em aberto</sub>

A questão foi concluida com a criação desta postagem:

> [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/70)

Já passou no "teste do tempo", foi claramente bem recebida pela comunidade e é uma referência comum para outras postagens.