# Perguntas Subjetivas

Tags: debate, perguntas, pergunta-subjetiva

Estou tendo um certo problema com uma pergunta, antes de faze-lá, li toda a ajuda para como fazer uma pergunta, acredito sim que me enquadro no que está sendo mostrado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> Algumas perguntas subjetivas são permitidas, mas “subjetivo” não
>   significa “qualquer coisa serve”. Todas as perguntas subjetivas devem
>   ser construtivas. O que significa isso? Perguntas subjetivas
>   construtivas:
>
> inspiram respostas que explicam “por que” e “como” costumam ter
>   respostas longas, não curtas têm um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial
>   convidam para compartilhar experiências e não opiniões insistem em que
>   as opiniões devem ser sustentadas com fatos e referências vão além da
>   diversão social insensível

Porem nada é aceito, tudo é suspenso e falam de melhorar e ninguém diz o que.

A pergunta que fiz foi a [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44158/comparativo-entre-ides-para-java), ja fiz várias edições, e já não sei o que mudar, ela não foi reaceita e eu fiquei sem resposta.

Queria saber exemplos práticos de tipos de perguntas subjetivas que são permitidas.

Comment: Espero que não me entendam mal, apenas não quero cometer mais erros quando for formular uma pergunta.

Comment: Lucas não sei se está a perceber, a pergunta pode ser bem objetiva, mas irá criar respostas bem subjetivas, de opinião. Assim como está agora é capaz de até dar algumas boas respostas. Mas mesmo assim acabará sempre por ser respondida com a opinião dos utilizadores que utilizaram os IDE's. Eu, que uso os 2, poderia dizer um sem número de vantagens de um e outro, na minha opinião. O que para mim é vantagem para outro pode ser desvantagem.

Answer (score 7):

Não adianta mudar umas palavras para dizer que editou. Tem edição que até piorou. Tem que deixar de ser subjetiva e principalmente deixar de ser ampla.

Aqui tem mais informações sobre o assunto: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective). Mas talvez seu caso até se encaixe em [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark).

Essas comparações são sempre tendenciosas mesmo quando a pessoa tenta ser imparcial. Pergunta objetiva é focada, ela diz sua necessidade concreta e pergunta qual atende aquilo. Você quer uma análise que nunca ninguém conseguiu fazer corretamente.

Do jeito que está perguntado, a resposta começará com "depende" e terá que listar dezenas, centenas ou milhares de cenários listando trocentos recursos sem esquecer de nada. Se esquecer a comparação fica torta e pode até atrapalhar mais que ajudar.

Leia estes *links* que passei e tente limitar o escopo. Se for o caso de precisar saber mais informações específicas faça outras perguntas. Tente reforçar como quer a resposta para evitar a opinião. Não garanto que resolverá mas ajudará.

Você estava certo em pedir experiências, mas ainda estava amplo então abre a porta para virar opinião.

Nas "respostas" que obteve nos comentário já mostra como é complicado. Tem gente que poderia dizer exatamente o oposto do que foi escrito lá. Então, quem está certo? O problema dessas perguntas é que ninguém pode certificar qual resposta está certa. Muito menos você. Você vai aceitar qual resposta? Vai instalar todos IDEs recomendados, usar por meses, concluir qual é o que te atende e vai escolher a resposta que indicou ela? Mas isto você pode fazer sem perguntar nada aqui. E na verdade é a única forma de fazer isto mesmo. Só você sabe o que te atende em termos gerais.

O que o *site* pode ajudar é responder se tem determinadas características. Só você pode dizer o que é melhor para você.

Comment: +1 pela última frase.

Comment: @bigown valeu pelo auxilio, posso estar sendo um pouco teimoso, mas é que realmente quero entender, os links estão me ajudando bastante.
Não tenho grande conhecimento, mas quero ajudar no possível, seja respondendo perguntas mais simples, ou editando...

Comment: Vocês acham que eu deveria excluir aquela pergunta?

Comment: @LucasMotta não acho que deve excluí-la, ela pode ter valor tanto para você quanto para outras pessoas, mas antes ela precisa ser respondível. Não to acompanhando muito bem o assunto mas vi que ela foi reaberta recentemente.

Comment: Sabe o tipo de resposta que eu esperava: - O ide1 tem melhor desempenho com hardware de baixo desempenho, o ide2 tem melhor conexão com o tal SGBD (Agora não tem mas na primeira pergunta era Postgre), o tal ide facilita a criacao de interface gráfica... Agora estou começando a perceber esse conceito de o que é facil pra mim, não é para o outro...

Comment: Algumas versões anteriores da pergunta estava mais focada que agora. Alguns usuários te atrapalharam. Eu acho que falta mais foco que querer opinião, embora isto exista um pouco também (pelo menos dá margem). O problema é: alguém pode dizer com certeza que há diferença significativa de desempenho? Você usou a palavra melhor. O que é melhor? Ninguém sabe. É subjetivo, é gosto.

Comment: Sim, estou entendendo, mas não sei se vocês concordam comigo, mas a resposta salvou a questão, já me decidi.

Comment: Mais uma coisa, perguntas no META tem que ser marcadas como respondidas?

Comment: Você decide aceitar se achar que respondeu o que você queria. O problema dessas perguntas é justamente este, você tomou uma decisão baseado em informações fracas. Eu que sou experiente jamais me decidiria algo importante porque uma pessoa aleatória na internet postou uma lista de características de dois produtos. Eu sei que ali não tem informação realmente útil para formar uma opinião pessoal. A não ser que você tivesse requisitos claros e escondeu de nós. Note que comentários mostram que a resposta é incompleta. E pode ser mais incompleta ainda do que já ficou aparente.

Comment: Aí se você mostrar porque escolheu um produto vai começar mostrar que sua pergunta realmente era cheia de falhas. Você ficou editando mas se recusando escrever o que faria você decidir por um ou outro. Nos comentários e na última edição já dá para ver que você escondeu informações relevantes (mesmo que não seja proposital) para a pergunta ser feita. Mas certamente você escondeu mais informações. Todo mundo dizendo para você ser específico no que precisa, para focar no que o produto tem que ser e você ficou deixando genérico, deixou Gorilla X Shark.