# Perguntas que envolvem principalmente opiniões são toleradas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Creio que a pergunta é bem objetiva e dispensa muitas explicações. De vez em quando tenho umas dúvidas que podem trazer respostas bem diversas, então acabo por não publicar aqui no site.

O intuito dessa pergunta é saber se existe um local dedicado a esses tipos de perguntas e se não, alguém poderia me recomendar algum fórum ou site parecido? Esses tipos de perguntas a que me refiro é como:

> "Você acha adequado utilizar tal tecnologia em tal coisa?"

Lembrando que as perguntas nunca sairiam do escopo do tema do site, todas relacionadas à programação.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não, há inclusive um critério de fechamento "Principalmente baseada em opiniões". Veja [esse tópico na Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para mais detalhes.

Isso não quer dizer, entretanto, que *todas* as perguntas com algum grau de subjetividade estão automaticamente vetadas. Veja o post ["Subjetivo Bom, Subjetivo Ruim"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/215), e talvez também o ["Gorilla vs. Shark"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/215). Em resumo, se sua pergunta puder ser respondida não na base de opiniões, mas de **experiência**, então *talvez* ela seja aceita no site apesar da margem que ela dá para subjetividade.

> Você acha adequado utilizar tal tecnologia em tal coisa?

- Sim, eu acho!
- Não, eu não acho!

Qual dessas respostas está "certa"? As duas, ou nenhuma, sei lá... Perguntar o que as pessoas acham pode ser útil em alguns casos (pesquisas de opinião) mas certamente está fora do escopo do StackOverflow em português.

> Quais os prós e contras de se usar tal tecnologia em tal coisa? Alguém já participou de um projeto desse tipo e teve sucesso? Quais os principais obstáculos que enfrentou, e em que circunstâncias a tecnologia se adaptou bem/mal ao problema em questão? Estou assumindo um cenário onde X, Y e Z são verdadeiros.

Aí já é uma pergunta mais "respondível". Se ela será aceita ou não pela comunidade, só perguntando pra saber, mas o importante é que da forma como a pergunta foi formulada há pouco espaço para opiniões levianas e exige-se um mínimo de conhecimento e/ou experiência para se dar uma resposta satisfatória.

Comment: Exatamente. Aqui não existe *um local* para esse tipo de pergunta, existe *uma maneira de fazê-las*. Uma pergunta como "Você acha adequado utilizar tal tecnologia em tal coisa?" possui pressupostos que devem estar explícitos na pergunta: "adequado" nas circunstâncias x,y,z; "tal tecnologia" seria usada de tal maneira; "tal coisa" vai servir para x. Explicitar essas coisas aumenta muito as chances da pergunta ser aceita, porque o universo de respostas possíveis diminui bastante.

Comment: Excelente resposta, é o que eu esperava. Eu estava dando uma de andarilho pelas dezenas de sites da rede SE e a cada site que visitava eu ficava mais indeciso qual site é o mais adequado para a pergunta em mente. Porém, todas as regras gerais (como essa mencionada nessa pergunta) se mantem para todos os sites, certo?

Comment: Que eu saiba, sim. Na dúvida, consulte a central de ajuda de cada site, e dê uma olhada rápida pra ver se há algo de muito diferente. Há sites de tudo quanto é tipo, então é natural que alguns possuam regras bem diferentes que outros. Em tempo: se uma pergunta está no escopo tanto do SOpt quanto de algum site em inglês, é permitido postar nos dois. Mas se está no escopo de dois ou mais sites em inglês, escolha um deles e poste só lá (não é permitido fazer *crosspost* em sites diferentes em inglês). Se há interseção, escolha um a seu gosto, o que achar que tem mas chance de ter uma boa resposta

Comment: Na dúvida pergunte aqui no meta se a pergunta x será aceite no site.