# Porque e que "Como iterar sobre um dicionário" foi fechada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

A pergunta [Como iterar sobre um dicionário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158220) foi fechada com o motivo: **`não está clara o suficiente`**.

Na minha perspetiva essa pergunta é bastante clara. Não precisa de informacoes adicionais, nem de exemplos, não tem informacão redundante nem contraditória.

Ela é apenas uma pergunta simples, breve e objetiva.

Para começar, na linguagem apontada **existe um conjunto de formas limitadas** de resolver o problema indicado pelo AP. Por este mesmo motivo uma resposta pode indicar as várias formas de resolver o problema e em que cenário cada forma pode ser aplicada. Foi isso que tentei fazer na minha resposta.

---

Porque é que a pergunta foi fechada?

Fica aqui um exemplo de [uma pergunta parecida na comunidade inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), que recebeu bastantes votos...

Comment: Quem fechou justificou nos comentarios logo abaixo da pergunta. Ao menos alguns deles.

Comment: @diegofm. Sim, mas nao concordo com eles.

Comment: Eu concordo com o dutto, está ampla demais, mas aguarde alguém prover uma resposta com melhores esclarecimentos.

Comment: A pergunta está muito ampla ou baseada em opiniões, ao meu ver.

Comment: @BrunoCosta talvez você possa editar. Mas como você disse: "Na sua espectativa" estava tudo bem, mas lembre-se que 5 pessoas analisaram a situação.

Comment: Desculpem pelos acentos mas o meu teclado e ingles... neste momento

Comment: Talvez não fosse o caso de "não clara" e sim "ampla" (de fato tiveram 2 votos). Há até quem achou, mas não votou que beira a opinião. Não tem contexto algum. Não estou afirmando, mas talvez esteja caindo no http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101. Claro que ela pode ser respondida, mas pode ser que interpretaram que as respostas estariam chutando o que ele quer, ou quem sabe que não tem problema definido. O que não parece ser um problema nesse caso. É um caso de zona cinzenta e não acho ela tão ruim. Poderia ser melhor.

Comment: Não são tão poucas formas. genericamente já são mais dos que as que estão nas respostas. Em casos concretos podem variar muito mais. Não estou dizendo que isso seja suficiente para fechar, mas é um indicador. **Talvez** seja até caso para falta de esforço (-1), mas não sei se para fechamento. Seria legal as pessoas darem boas justificativas para o voto, já que a pergunta dá alguns argumentos favoráveis à pergunta. Vamos ver como a discussão aqui evolui.

Comment: Não acho um pergunta ruim, talvez reabrindo e melhorando o contexto já bastaria e as respostas são boas, na minha visão ajuda a comunidade.

Comment: Só lembrando que o fato da pergunta estar fechada não invalida a qualidade das respostas. Pode ocorrer da pergunta ser ruim e fechada, mas antes obter respostas boas.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta do `AP`, mas acho que a minha edicao pode cair como `muda as intencoes do autor`. Eu preferia que esta edicao fosse aceite por ele, mas isso nao funiona assim...

Comment: Além de mudar a intenção inicial da pergunta, com essa alteração ela me parece se encaixar como ampla demais. Como já dito, não teríamos como responder todas as formas de se iterar sobre um dicionário...

Comment: @jbueno O problema e que voce pode. se nao me engano so existem 3 formas. Todas as outras sao combinacoes dessas 3

Comment: Eu continuo achando que não tem como. E também continuo achando que a pergunta é irrelevante pro site, mas este é só o meu voto, temos ainda vários usuários para ajudar a decidir...

Comment: @diegofm a questão de reabrir é se é possível receber novas respostas boas. Notem que a dúvida de certa forma é conceitual. Eu vejo problemas na pergunta, mas não sei se não dá para responder de forma minimamente adequada. Não acho as respostas ruins, mas também não cobrem tudo o que pode ser falado, já que a pergunta não foca. Veja motivos para fechar e para deixar aberta.

Comment: De que edição vocês estão falando? Não vi a pergunta sendo editada.

Comment: Sugestão de edição @bigown o AP tem < 2k de reputação. Aliás, a sugestão já foi negada.

Comment: Ah, foi rejeitada. Acho que bem, porque só encheu linguiça e não acrescentou nada útil que ajudasse dar melhor entendimento, por isso não muda a intenção do autor.

Comment: @bigown Eu tentei reformular a pergunta basicamente apenas para retirar o problema de `formas padrao` pelos vistos falhei a milhas...

Comment: @BrunoCosta, aliás, o que quer dizer "*Porque e que [...]*"?

Comment: Você respondeu à sua própria pergunta: "Por este mesmo motivo uma resposta pode indicar varias formas de resolver o problema e em que cenário cada forma pode ser aplicada", ou seja, é muito ampla.

Comment: @JorgeB.  era para ter escrito `indicar as varias formas` e nao `indicar varias formas`. Como eu ja expliquei, no meu ver, existe um conjunto limitado.

Comment: A questão é que **existir um conjunto limitado** não contrapõe a amplitude. O conjunto limitado pode ser 15 maneiras.

Comment: Mas nao ,e um numero variavel. E um numero fixo porque a linguagem so lhe permite que faca dessas formas... Como ja mencionei todas as outras sao derivacoes dessas. Axo que vou procurar uma coisa no site... Ja digo qualquer coisa...

Comment: @jbueno Nao encontrei nesta comunidade, mas tenha em atencao por exemplo [uma pergunta bastante parecida na comunidade inglesa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) e a resposta aceite.

Comment: Perceba que a pergunta lá é um pouco mais específica (particularmente eu acho que existiriam outros motivos para ela ser fechada, mas não vem ao caso) porque o AP quer saber alguma forma de iterar sobre a coleção de dados. Mas o mais importante é que [aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1/18246), somos uma comunidade diferente.

Comment: @jbueno Tudo bem, eu respeito e concordo com isso. So estou a chamar atencao para outros utilizadores considerarem com base nessa pergunta.

Comment: Vou aguardar mais participações até tomar uma decisão.

Comment: Só um adendo, eu diria que a resposta mostrou que a pergunta ou resultado final é baseado em opiniões

Comment: Eu acho ampla. O fato de por acaso ter um limite de possibilidades é mero desdobramento. Então se tivéssemos 150 maneiras, iriamos colocar todas sem nenhum contexto? Acho que falta uma definição melhor no que está sendo buscado com a pergunta. Inclusive, sabe se lá o que o autor entende por "padrão"?

Comment: @bacco Nao pode atirar números de 3 dígitos para o ar só para parecer muito e desqualificar a pergunta. De todas as linguagens que conheço nenhuma passa dos 2 dígitos e o mais certo e nem chegaram as 2 dezenas. Em vez de negativar a resposta pode edita-la para conter mais conteúdo e pedir ao autor para tornar resposta de comunidade. Pode também dar a sua resposta para complementar outras hipóteses.

Comment: Olha é apenas uma opinião minha, mas quando uma resposta começa assim *Eu diria que sim,* e o exemplo citado ou texto descrito não cita uma fonte oficial de algum padrão (no minimo acho que teria ser da MS) então me parece mais uma coisa de experiencia ou que a maioria usa, mas isso não torna algo padronizado, só torna como sendo algo de uso comum.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Na verdade eu prefiro votar para fechar a pergunta mesmo (que foi o que eu fiz) e esperar o autor dar mais detalhes. Da forma como está, entendo como ampla e em dúvida sobre estar no escopo. Não vejo problema objetivo, e o "bem definido" me é duvidoso. Não vou entrar no jogo bobo dos dígitos, pois isso sim é tentativa de desqualificar o comentário mudando o foco para um ponto irrelevante. (que fique claro que o "bobo" foi usado no sentido de improdutivo, não no sentido pessoal).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas estamos a falar da minha resposta ou da pergunta?... Eu nao percebo. Eu fiz a minha resposta baseada da forma como a pergunta foi feita se a pergunta fosse feita doutra forma talvez responde-se sem `Eu diria que sim`. Eu tentei fazer uma edicao na pergunta para remover a parte da `forma padrao` , mas parece que a fiz de forma errada.

Comment: @BrunoCosta a sua resposta e a outra mostrar o resultado do tipo da pergunta, você esta confundindo "padronização" com "uso comum", vou formular uma resposta. Vou tentar formular uma resposta aqui ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nao sei se estou porque tanto quanto sei, neste caso o uso comum e igual a padronizacao, uma vez que existem formas limitadas de alcancar o objetivo. Por haverem formas limitadas todas elas estao padronizadas e todas elas sao relativamenmte comuns...

Comment: @BrunoCosta uma padronização necessita de uma fonte de um consorcio como w3 que seria para html e css para definir as coisas, uso comum é outra coisa. Eu formulei uma resposta, espero que lhe seja util.

Comment: A pergunta ficou muito vaga, falta detalhes, falta contexto e faltou um pouco de esforço de pesquisa. Qual dicionário o AP deseja fazer a interação? A respeito do padrão existe as formas convencionais suportadas pela sintaxe do C#. E curiosamente sua pergunta se parece muito com [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c). Existe varias resposta e cada uma mostrando uma forma, realmente não a muito ganho nisso, porque não explica a fundo só mostra a sintaxe e a corrida pelo tal "padrão" que não sabemos em qual contexto sera usado.

Comment: A pergunta já está reaberta. Apenas reforcei com positivos. Mas vejo aqui mais um exemplo de equívoco em fechar um pergunta e ainda negativam. Uma pergunta idêntica a essa no SO-en possui mais de 1200 positivos e diversas respostas cuja mais votada tem mais de 2 mil votos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já disse nos comentários que vejo motivos para fechar e para manter aberta.

Os argumentos do AP parecem ser mais convincentes que os argumentos contrários.

## Escopo

A pergunta claramente está dentro do escopo. Alguns podem argumentar que isso pode ser facilmente achado, que é só ler manual, ou algo assim. Mais isso nunca impediu perguntas na rede.

## Esforço

Se alguém disser que a pergunta não demandou esforço algum, o autor não fez uma pesquisa prévia, não tentou colocar um contexto, mostrar que não jogou a pergunta de qualquer jeito só para ganhar reputação, eu tendo a concordar. Não sei se daria -1 nela, mas não acho um caso absurdo. O tema é interessante, mas a pergunta em si está mal formulada.

## Por que fechar uma pergunta?

A questão é se dá para responder ou não. Esse é ponto a ser analisado se deve deixar fechada ou não.

## Baseada em opinião

Ela não é baseada em opinião. Ela sequer quer saber [qual é melhor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141088/221800) (note que ela foi [fechada uma vez, reaberta por um CM](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/141088/revisions) e mesmo depois de vários anos não foi fechada novamente, com todo o movimento que teve). O que nem é um problema por si só. Veja que o SO, que é mais rígido que nós, aceitou uma pergunta assim sem problemas. Ela é objetiva. Se ainda não leu tem a oportunidade de ver o [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101). Lá mostra que o fechamento por ser baseado em opinião é para evitar respostas bobas que não levam a lugar algum. É para evitar do "eu gosto disso", "isso é legal", ou mesmo algo mais palpável, mas que é controverso e não há base alguma. A pergunta é culpada quando ela claramente pede por opinião, não basta dar margem. Ainda que se der margem, é melhor editar.

Mesmo sem fontes não significa que respostas são baseadas em opinião. Depende do senso comum, depende do relato. Complicado é a pessoa postar algo que pode ser negado por outras pessoas, que ela force uma situação afirmando algo que é opinião como se fosse verdade, coloque gosto como se fosse fato. Mesmo um dose de opinião não é problema se a parte objetiva da resposta responder o que foi perguntado. Se tudo precisar de fonte, 99,9% das respostas aqui devem estar erradas. Fontes são necessárias quando é pedido ou quando há controvérsias. Argumentos fundamentados são válidos.

Mas a pergunta nem pede opiniões. E como eu já argumentei outras vezes, se formos rígidos com o que é opinião, e o critério "oficial" é bem pouco rígido (recomendo a todos lerem com cuidado), praticamente qualquer resposta é baseada em opinião. Qualquer algoritmo que você escreva carrega uma dose de opinião, por mais que ela seja certa, funcione, faz o que tem que fazer, outras pessoas usem. É o jeito que você achou que devia ser. Outras pessoas podem achar que deveria ser feito da mesma forma. E todas estarem certas.

Mais ainda, usando esse critério de que só pode ter uma resposta certa, seria um absurdo o site ter uma estatística de sucesso que pede no mínimo 2,5 respostas por pergunta. E se só existe um jeito certo de fazer as demais, só poderiam ser postadas se fosse cópias umas das outras. O objetivo é oposto deste.

Muitas vezes é que quem dá a melhor explicação que conta. Aí tem uma dose de opinião também. Mas tudo dentro da normalidade.

Isto é uma pergunta ruim, o cara que fez não bate bem: [What's the most absurd myth about programming issues?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1745/389). Tem outra que não é boa para um formato de Q&A: [What's your favourite quote about programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/39/389) e olha que ela tem alguma utilidade.

## Não clara

A pergunta é tão simples que não tem como estar mais clara. Ele quer saber as diferentes formas de iterar um dicionário em C#. O problema não está muito específico, mas é uma questão mais conceitual e sua aplicação prática. Novamente não está formulada da melhor forma possível, mas dá para responder.

## Muito ampla

Ampla talvez? Teve um voto, me pareceu o único que foi no ponto certo. Mas note que ser ampla é diferente de ser muito ampla.

Ela não é por permitir muitas respostas. Perguntas que gerem muitas respostas só são ruins se for do tipo *poll question*, ou seja, vários usuários colocam sua forma preferida e a comunidade vai votando, o que tiver mais votos é a preferida. E o AP escolhe qual, a preferida dele? Não é para isso que existe um site de perguntas respostas. A resposta não resolve problema algum, foi escolhida quase ao acaso e as respostas tendem serem superficiais demais, até mesmo incorrendo em opinião. Ele pede uma resposta que mostra as diversas formas.

Se ele tivesse pedido uma forma única talvez fosse pior, poderia cair em *poll question*, mas a pergunta seria mais aceita. Tá cheio de [pergunta assim no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14719955/221800).

É ampla porque pede quase um capítulo de um livro? Provavelmente. Mas se analisarmos o contexto ela pode ser respondida talvez com uma forma só. Mas também pode ser respondida em algo longo.

Longo não é o problema, desde que não seja um tutorial completo. Temos que tratar certas perguntas diferentemente. Alguém pedir para fazer tudo para ela, mesmo que indiretamente, mesmo que fazer tudo seja 3 linhas de códigos, pode ser ampla. Falta informação para responder exatamente o que o autor queria.

Essa pergunta dá para saber exatamente, não precisa muito de limites, ainda que se tivesse mais contexto seria melhor, a resposta poderia ser um pouco mais direcionada. Falar porque quer saber, onde está querendo usar, algo assim pode ajudar. Faltou observar o [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101).

## Porque existe o fechamento?

Fechamos perguntas que provavelmente serão, ou já são problemáticas, mas nem tudo é problema. Exemplos:

- já existe no site
- não é um assunto que nos diz respeito
- não está escrita em forma esperada
- **só atende quem perguntou** (ainda que se isso fosse levado a ferro e fogo, quase tudo seria fechado)
- é uma tentativa de discutir ou obter informação boba, vai ajudar zero pessoas na realidade (é comum a pessoa achar que vai ajudar)
- "ninguém" que entende do assunto consegue ler a pergunta e saber **exatamente** do que se trata
- é confuso demais, a pergunta não bate com resposta aceita ou pode trazer outras indicações erradas para futuros leitores
- quer uma lista de coisas para escolher uma delas
- quer um curso sobre o assunto
- quer tudo pronto

Alguns casos o fechamento deve ser temporário.

Alguns casos cabe negativação e/ou remoção (nem é uma pergunta, por exemplo), mas isso é outro assunto.

Eu percebo que há muito entendimento errado sobre quais são os motivos de fechamento e ainda vou falar sobe isso futuramente. O mesmo ocorre com sinalizações, o que provoca rejeições.

Tem momentos que estamos mais restritivos que o SO, que sempre foi considerado restritivo demais. O objetivo do [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/18246) é que possamos ser menos restritivos.

Eu sempre fui contra a criação de novos critérios do que se costuma adotar na rede. Ser mais flexível que o SO sempre foi o objetivo, aceitar qualquer coisa eu sempre odiei. Mas eu tenho a impressão que aqui está se criando critérios que não existem na rede, só que para o outro lado. Querem fechar mais do que o normal.

Eu acho que devemos nos concentrar nas perguntas que eu costumo chamar duramente de *lixo*. Eu sei que algumas pessoas não gostam quando uso termos mais pesados, mas eles são usados bastante no metão por CMs. Eles não costumam poupar conteúdo ruim.

A pergunta não está uma maravilha, mas pode produzir algo útil para muita gente.

Qual é o problema que ela está causando se ficar aberta? Deturpa o mecanismo? Vai haver uma corrida de respostas sem nexo a troco de nada? Vai acabar ficando sem resposta? Vai servir só para o autor?

No passado acho que era bom um certo cuidado, hoje acho que precisa menos. Claro que precisa usar o bom senso e tentar responder o que dá.

## Não gosto da pergunta

O fato do AP não se preocupar em melhorar me desagrada. As pessoas precisam se dedicar um pouco mais ao que deseja saber, senão fica parecendo que apenas postou alguma para participar, ganhar reputação sem compromisso. Pode fazer isso? Pode, mas eu não gosto.

Não gostar da forma como a pergunta foi feita acho normal, mas fechar me parece que não precisa. Não gostar e ser ruim para manter aberta no site são coisas distintas.

Em casos assim é melhor tentar editar. O objetivo é salvar perguntas e não fechar.

Eu queria ver argumentos que mostram que a pergunta está tão ruim que não pode ser respondida adequadamente.

## O tema é bom

Algumas das melhores respostas aqui e no SO saíram de perguntas assim. O conteúdo que ela pode gerar é atrativo, a forma como ela foi feita não é, mas dá para responder. Esse me parece um caso que se é para "punir" que seja só a pergunta. Acho que ela poderia ser melhorada pelo autor.

Até para argumentar com o que foi colocado em comentários. Responder "não, isso não existe" é uma resposta razoável, curta e objetiva e baseada em opinião se acharem que tem que ter fonte para tudo. Provar a inexistência de alguma coisa é bem mais difícil que existência. Então vamos acreditar na existência sem provas porque a inexistência não foi provada?

Se um dia alguém provar o contrário, tem solução. Não sair de casa porque pode levar um tiro não parece ser a solução.

Tem precedente: [Organização de CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34996/101). Me lembro que ela foi vem debatida, não lembro se no meta, chat ou entre alguns usuários específicos fora do site. Eu não queria que ficasse aberta, me convenceram e até respondi.

## Respostas existentes

Eu acho uma delas boa, não vejo problemas reais nela, a outra tem problemas, mas não é culpa da pergunta, é autor sem noção de como a linguagem funciona. Isso qualquer pergunta corre o risco.

## Melhor reabrir

Não me importaria de mantê-la fechada. Mas por...

- minha convicção pessoal,
- falta de bons argumentos para fechamento,
- ter perguntas com estrutura semelhante deliberadamente abertas<sup>*</sup>,
- ter voto para reabrir de quem entende do assunto e do funcionamento do site,
- joguei na sala dos moderadores, ninguém deu opinião para deixar fechada,
- ver várias perguntas nesse estilo no SO,

eu acho que é melhor reabri-la.

Eu respondi uma hoje muito pior e ninguém falou nada. Só que tinha mais que uma linha, pareceu que era ótima.

Eu poderia fazer uma pergunta melhor sobre o assunto e responder, mas vou nela mesmo. Vou responder para mostrar que dá para responder bem, produzir algo útil, que é o nosso interesse principal. Também vou mostrar que ela é um pouco ampla sim, que a resposta será, ou só tem um jeito, ou tem infinitos jeitos. O que não deixa de ser uma resposta. Vou mostrar alguns.

Me desculpem os que discordam, mas esse caso me parece que há mais benefício em manter aberta. Se alguém me convencer, eu mudo de ideia. Eu tenho tentando evitar tomar decisões monocráticas, mas estou seguro que esse é um caso para fazer.

A avaliação é subjetiva. Eu entendo as motivações de quem votou para fechar, principal quem votou ampla, mas acho que foi o erro. Espero eu não estar cometendo outro em reabrir.

Se for para fechar, fechem novamente pelo motivo certo.

---

<sup>*</sup>Eu acho que o fechamento tem a ver com o tamanho da pergunta e não com seu conteúdo, se o AP tivesse se esforçado mais não teriam votado para fechar.

Comment: Motivos de fechamento de "**só atende quem perguntou**" e "**só ajuda o autor da pergunta**" não são mais considerados válidos no SOen (e aqui nunca foram). Lá foram considerados válidos no passado, mas acabava servindo apenas para incentivar abusos no fechamento e práticas de *no soup for you*, e por isso foram abolidos.

Comment: @VictorStafusa São sim considerados sim, lá e aqui, tanto que existe uma opção para isso, ela só não é mais a opção principal, virou uma opção secundária do fora de escopo. Só mudou a forma justamente para não ser usado para tudo, foi dado uma semântica mais específico do que é válido fechar desta forma.

Answer (score 3):

Quero ressaltar a diferença entre ambos exemplos que citou:

- [Como iterar sobre um dicionário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158220/3635)

  Nesta pergunta a sua resposta foi mais algo de uso comum e você começou dizendo *"Eu diria que sim"* e o autor da outra resposta disse algo como *"Segue duas formas que são bastante usadas"* e com isso é importante notar que o AP perguntou se existe um padrão e não qual é o mais usado.
- [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446/1518921)

  Já esta pergunta gerou respostas que citaram fontes de documentações ou do http://ecma-international.org essa é a diferença básica entre ambos exemplos (do SOpt e SOen).

Para deixar claro, eu não acho a pergunta aqui no SOpt de todo mal, pelo contrário eu acho ela objetiva, o problema é o tipo de respostas que ela gerou, se o AP especificar melhor algo não vejo mal em reabrir a pergunta, mas eu vou ser sincero não concordo em nada com ambas respostas que a pergunta gerou, pois:

- Falam do que é um uso mais comum
- Não citam fontes oficiais

No final parece mais gosto de uso por A do que por B e não me parece que foi o que o AP pediu.

### O que é padronização?

Padronização ou normalização é o processo de desenvolvimento e implementação de normas técnicas <sup>(Wiki)</sup>, eu acredito que para algo ser uma padronização tem que existir um site, documento ou documentação no minimo afirmando um uso preferencial, como por exemplo:

- http://w3.org para xml, svg, html, css (e algumas coisas mais)
- http://ecma-international.org para Javascript

Comment: Parece-me bem vou tentar editar a minha resposta para incluir uma fonte mais ou menos oficial.

Comment: @BrunoCosta excelente :) ... me avise quando fizer para eu ler, quem sabe ganhará uns upvotes, até mais!

Comment: [Curiosamente a comunidade inglesa tem uma pergunta igual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

Comment: @BrunoCosta a pergunta é de 2008, as pessoas não tinham parametros para comparar naquela época, Q&A era uma coisa muito nova, tem muita resposta ruim desse ano, eu mesmo tive duas perguntas minhas que levaram 2 anos para serem fechadas, comecei em 2013, só fecharam em 2015. Por incrivel que pareça se fecharam essa no SOpt é porque hoje somos muito mais organizados e a comunidade em portugues é bem menor, o que facilita fechar o que deve ser fechado...

Comment: @BrunoCosta ...E se você olhar bem tem uma diferença sutil entre ambas perguntas, lá no SOen ele pergunta qual a melhor e se tem um padrão, ou seja você não precisaria afirmar sobre o padrão, bastaria citar "o melhor". Bruno se quiser participar do chat conosco basta acessar http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: @BrunoCosta Se olhar as [revisões](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/141088/revisions) da pergunta que você citou, verá que ela foi fechada lá também. E, naquele caso, foi reaberta por um moderador e não pela comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Veja, na [central de ajuda, existe uma página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) que diz o seguinte:

> #### A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?
>
> O Stack Overflow é voltado para programadores profissionais e estudantes, pessoas que escrevem programas por amor. Acreditamos que as melhores perguntas no Stack Overflow têm sempre um pouco de código, mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...
>
> - um problema específico de programação
> - um algorítmo de software
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software
>
> … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

Eu não vejo a pergunta citada se encaixando em nenhum destes itens. Claro que isso pode depender de interpretação individual e, possivelmente, é por isso que o sistema pede 5 votos para fechamento. Ou seja, outras 4 pessoas (além de uma que se manifestou pelos comentários) acham que esta pergunta não está dentro do esperado pela comunidade.

A pergunta também é **muito ampla**, várias respostas poderiam se encaixar como correta, como dito pelo bigown, "*não são tão poucas formas que existem, genericamente falando, já são mais do que existem nas respostas*".

Ela também tem uma pitada de **principalmente baseada em opinões**, afinal, não existe um padrão (aliás, como poderia existir?) como o AP pede no corpo da publicação. Cada caso é um caso e dependeria de contexto se fossemos ajudar o AP a escolher uma forma para "resolver o tal problema", acho que isso pode justificar a pergunta como ***não clara** também, porque não existe contexto.

Comment: Aí seria fora de escopo, certo?

Comment: Sim, eu publiquei sem querer enquanto escrevia...

Comment: no meu ver a pergunta se encaixa em `um  problema específico de programação`, assim como `problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software`

Comment: @BrunoCosta `problema específico` não se encaixa, de específico esse problema não tem nada. O último item parece ser mais adequado.

Answer (score 1):

Deixa eu postar meu ponto de vista para tentar esclarecer alguns pontos como a motivação para fazer a pergunta e, principalmente, pontos da documentação do SO.

Eu tinha um problema que para resolver eu precisaria percorrer um dicionário `Dictionary<string, string>`. Na empresa não usamos `var` nem `Linq` - o motivo não cabe ao tópico. Enfim, na `web` eu achei o tipo `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` que resolveu o meu problema:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dicionary) {}
```

Resolveu, por pouco tempo. Quando precisei de modificar o dicionário e começar a trabalhar com `values` de `tuplas` junto com strings, o meu `foreach` quebrou:

Não funcionava:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dicionary) {}
```

Não funcionava:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Tuple(int, int)> kvp in dicionary) {}
```

E não funcionava:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dicionary) {}
```

Então, resolvi meu problema com a ajuda de alguém da equipe usando:

```
foreach(string key in dicionary.Keys) {
    // recupera a kvp por dictionary[key]
}
```

Isso porque as keys continuavam sendo `strings`.

Bom, por enquanto funciona. Quando a key deixar de ser somente `string` e começar a ser `string` e `tupla`, vou ter que endereçar as keys por `objects` e o meu código vai voltar a quebrar.

Daí, a minha motivação de escrever o post, eu descobri que eu não sabia iterar sobre um dicionário e, somado à isso, não tinha nenhum post no fórum que respondesse a essa pergunta. Então, escrevi o post para futuras dúvidas sobre o assunto e abrir discussão sobre as limitações de diferentes tipos de iterações.

Pra finalizar, eu considero a pergunta conveniente - do ponto de vista da documentação do fórum - porque:

- é um problema específico de computação: atentem-se ao fato de que podem ter respostas abertas e se tiver, podem ser passíveis de sinalização, mas problema é específico. Como iterar sobre um dicionário é específico. Se existem ou não padrões é um dúvida específica. Aqui não cabem achismos.
- é um problema prático e bem definido no que diz respeito ao desenvolvimento de software: essa é a principal motivação do post, oras. Se eu to perguntando "como se itera em um dicionário" foi porque, de alguma forma, eu tive esse problema quando precisava iterar sobre um.

Eu respeito muito dúvidas com uma única resposta possível mas acho que em essência não é só para esse tipo de pergunta que fórum existe. Se uma pergunta tem muitas formas diferentes de se resolver, é importante deixar espaço para discutimos as vantagens e desvantagens das mais importantes delas.

Comment: Devia de ter mencionado essas restricoes na sua pergunta... O correto nesse caso seria o `foreach` com `KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>`

Comment: não é.. é que o dicionário é <string, object> porque os values podem ser string ou tupla(int, int) e iterar kvp<string, object> não funcionava.. sacou?

Comment: Ah... entendi agora.

Comment: Se o dicionario era mesmo `<string, object>` o `KeyValuePair<string, object>` **tem que compilar**

Comment: Sua pergunta lá não tem nada a ver com o que está postando aqui. Se era isso que queria saber deveria ter perguntado isso e não outra coisa. Eu reabri a pergunta lá, mas ela não pode ser fundamentalmente mudada já que existem respostas. Não pode querer saber uma coisa e perguntar outra. Pergunte o que quer saber de fato. Agora virá argumentos para ter a pergunta fechada porque você não passou nem perto da sua intenção. A melhor coisa que pode fazer para salvar aquela pergunta era considerar ela mais abstrata mesmo e que era aquilo que queria, e vai fazer outra sobre esse *outro * problema.