# Onde posso fazer indicação de ferramentas?

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de saber se existe uma sessão específica para indicar ferramentas de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 8):

Não existe. Em geral esse tipo de pergunta cai no que [não deve perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Claro que pode falar sobre isso no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Aí fala em indicar ferramentas e não pedir ferramentas indicadas. Isso provavelmente não vai dar certo. Provavelmente ficará com cara de *spam*. Mesmo não sendo.

Se quer pedir recomendações de ferramentas, não é que não pode, mas tem que fazer bem feito. Tem que fazer de forma que dê uma produzir uma resposta objetiva. Se der [margem demais para opiniões](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101), a pergunta será fechada.

Se a pergunta for aberta demais, e quiser só uma lista sem significado de opções que na verdade não ajuda tanto quanto a pessoa imagina, onde a melhor resposta será por puro acaso, que só atenderá um gosto e não resolverá um problema real, [provavelmente será fechada por ser ampla](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101).

Mas pode ser que seja fechada como não clara porque não tem informações mínimas para saber o que deseja.

Raro, mas eventualmente este tipo de pergunta acaba sendo de uma forma tão ruim que acaba sendo fechada como fora de escopo, porque a pessoa não quer uma resposta mesmo.

Eu estou pensando sobre o assunto e bolando uma forma de atender essa necessidade. Mas ainda não concluir sobre todas implicações e estou aguardando sobre como algumas coisas se desenrolam no site, é preciso ter certeza que o site está preparado para isto. Tenho feito alguns experimentos que ninguém percebe para resolver certos problemas. Se eles forem bem já ajuda adotar um caminho adequado para este tipo de demanda que não funciona bem em um site de Q&A (perguntas respostas). Quando eu tiver algo bem formatado eu posto aqui.

Eu até acho que a dona do site deveria criar uma ferramenta que contemplasse melhor esse tip ode coisa. Algo como ela fez com o [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation), que deve ter sua versão em português entre [6 a 8 semanas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). Entendo que há outra prioridades, mas pelo menos uma sinalização que estão pensando nisso seria legal. Tem várias demandas de profissionais de TI que não cabem em um Q&A. A rede Stack Exchange poderia ser o melhor local para profissionais trocarem informações, não importa o formato. Mas precisa da ferramenta adequada.

Comment: `Algo como ela fez com o Stack Overflow Documentation, que deve ter sua versão em português entre 6 a 8 semanas.` - ´serio que teremos o doc em 2/3 meses? :o

Comment: @diegofm leia o *link*.

Comment: Está em inglês. Mas agora vi que parece se tratar de um meme. Que pena.