# até que ponto perguntas de opinião são permitidas

Tags: debate, como-perguntar

Recentemente, me veio algumas duvidas que poderiam virar perguntas no fórum, porem, parando pra pensar, as repostas teriam mas opinião que certezas. por exemplo,se eu perguntasse:

Qual o melhor compilador para c++ ? G++ ou Clang ?

Provavelmente as  respostas viriam mostrando pontos positivos e negativos de cada compilador, porem também com a opinião das pessoas a respeito de cada compilador, oque seria muito bom para mim, porque era isso que eu gostaria de saber. Mas, provavelmente essa pergunta seria expulsa do fórum por conter "opinião de mais". Oque em muitos casos é correto, mas em outros, como no caso da pergunta exemplificada, eu acho que não.

Então, até que ponto uma pergunta pode ser excluída só porque não existe uma reposta que todo mundo concorde ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não são permitidas e esta me parece claramente uma que é baseada em opinião de uma forma negativa. Se acha que não precisa justificar, argumentar.

Claro que se a pergunta for escrita em outra forma é possível sair alguma coisa útil. Mas não é fácil. Até é fácil sair da opinião, é só não perguntar qual é o melhor e passar pedir as diferenças. Mas ainda será ampla. Precisaria se concentrar em um aspecto específico ou para uma necessidade específica.

Um depende nem sempre é de todo mal, mas uma pergunta muito aberta também abre a porta para muitos dependes. Vai cair no caso do [Gorila X Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101). Mas tem como fugir dessa batalha inverossímil.

Uma coisa que muitos não entendem é que estas regras são para limitar o uso das perguntas sem um motivo real, só por curiosidade. Se o motivo é real dá para detalhar bem, colocar um contexto, impor limites do que é uma resposta aceitável, e principalmente se a pergunta é importante a pessoa gastará um pouco de tempo lapidando a pergunta para sair grandes respostas.

Eu acho curioso que em muitos casos quando a pessoa recebe instruções de como melhorar a pergunta para ser aceitável, ela desiste, acha que dá trabalho demais. Para ela o site é feito por um bando de chatos e para os mais ativos do site de Q&A este perguntador em específico acaba ficando com a imagem de folgado, *troll* ou algo parecido, mesmo que a pessoa não seja e a intenção fosse outra. Mas como sabemos "de boas intenções o inferno está cheio".

Nós devemos presumir boa intenção, mas por mais que seja bem intencionado, nem tudo produzirá bons resultados.

Eu acho que pode sair coisa boa daí se a pergunta for feita adequadamente, para um problema real (ou fictício, mas muito, muito bem definido mesmo). A dica foi dada de como deixar a questão fechada para não ser fechada :P