# Vamos falar sobre padronização de código?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Sempre senti vontade de fazer algumas perguntas sobre padronização de código, claro que isso é muito pessoal..... Mas levando em conta que a maioria dos cursos ensina um padrão que muitas vezes discordamos, e a maioria das empresas acabam por abordar um padrão de programação, e todo dev concorda que quanto mais legível e limpo o código, melhor, não seria interessante termos perguntas desse tipo? Onde cada um não somente exponha sua opinião, quanto mostraria os prós e contras de se utilizar uma forma ou a outra.

Tipo nesse git que encontrei abordando sobre padrões de código:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comparison--nested-ternaries

Pegando js/typescript como exemplo:

"O que acham que fica mais legível, ou existe forma mais legivel? E em quais casos se aplicaria cada forma?"

```
let initialOptions =
  (userType === personType ? 
    [emptyOption, allOptions] : 
    [selectOption, allOptions]
  );
```

ou

```
let initialOptions = userType === personType ? [emptyOption, allOptions] : [selectOption, allOptions];
```

Outro exemplo que poderia entrar com o mesmo contexto:

```
let a = "a",
    b = "b",
    c = "c";
```

ou

```
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
let c = "c";
```

Comment: Três palavras: [tag:estilo-de-codificação]

Comment: Então, esse tipo de pergunta, é válida? Eu sempre tive receio de fazer esses tipos de pergunta por achar algo muito pessoal e parecer baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Atualmente acho que não seria válida, já que é baseada em opinião. Mas acho que deveria ser válida.

Comment: Não há nada que seja baseado em opinião se souber fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Esta forma de perguntar não parece legal, mas dá para saber quase o mesmo do jeito certo, existe uma diferença entre saber o que cada um gosta e qual o fundamento pra usar uma coisa ou outra.

Comment: Teria um exemplo @Maniero? Porque todo tipo de estilo estrutural de codificação é melhor de um jeito pra um e melhor de outro jeito pra outro.

Comment: Perguntar assim: "Qual é melhor SASS ou LESS" isso é baseado em opinião, mas perguntar assim: "Quais as vantagens do SASS sobre o LESS elas existem?" Já é bem diferente, Pelo menos é o que eu penso com a minha opinião :)

Comment: @RobertodeCampos isso é uma visão errada, as pessoas acham isso porque elas não tem pensamento científico, crítico, questionador, elas seguem receita de bolo dos outros, seguem as tais "boas práticas", este tipo de pergunta serve justamente pra quebrar a ideia que cada um faz do jeito que quiser, que é gosto. Claro, tem coisa que é gosto, mas a maioria não, tem um motivo, tem uma explicação. Acho essas perguntas boas até pra acabar com a ideia que isso é questão de gosto. Depois de explicado cada pode adotar ou não, pode ir pelo seu gosto ou não, mas saberá porque e escolhe ou teima em algo.

Comment: Cheio de exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estilo-de-codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: @hugocsl claro que isso é só o título, mas se for só isso provavelmente é ampla :) https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101

Comment: [Aqui um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14461/jquery-click-ou-function) de pergunta que não acho tão errada, inclusive a resposta dada foi excelente, mas que inclusive foi fechada. Claro que ele envolveu jquery, ai se perde um pouco do contexto, mas a pergunta de se é melhor usar chamada de função inline ou desvinculado do html, acho bem boa

Comment: @MarceloBoni esse é o caso que a resposta (uma delas) até salva a pergunta, mas a pergunta em si muito claramente pergunta qual é o melhor, não que a palavra deve ser o motivo de fechar, mas ele não faz mais anada que ajude responder de outra forma, por sorte responderam.

Comment: A dúvida é pertinente, só não sei onde caberia como uma pergunta...talvez um bate-papo mais informal... como o @Maniero disse, é um estilo e também as pessoas costumam receber receita de bolo pronta, mas quanto mais críticos ficamos e pensamos, começamos a discutir o que é o melhor.. eu mesmo tenho críticas ao tão consagrado modelo OO, mas isso é assunto pra outra hora, de preferência acompanhado de uma breja :)

Comment: de qualquer forma, mais que o estilo, talvez se pautar em duas coisas: o simples e o claro. Você pode escrever uma expressão toda em uma linha, mas não vai simplificar e sim dificultar pra outro que veja seu código, então por que não separar em várias linhas? por que fazer vários ìf` se uma expressão booleada resolve? mas também, é claro o código? Isso é subjetivo, mas se pensar sempre em deixar o código claro e simples já um bom princípio... se colocar uma expressão em uma linha ou várias, o código compilado será o mesmo, então deixe claro, pense que outras pessoas podem utilizar seu código