# Qual o motivo fechamento para quando o usuário só quer uma garibada no código

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento, escopo-do-site

O usuário fez essa pergunta [Prototipo de aplicativo em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449379/prototipo-de-aplicativo-em-python).

O código não apresenta nenhum erro: https://repl.it/repls/StaticElaborateHertz

O AP quer apenas que deem uma melhorada no código.

Eu quero saber se a pergunta é válida para o site ou motivo correto para o fechamento é:

- > Apesar de ser sobre programação, esta pergunta não parece atender os
  >   critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um site de
  >   perguntas e respostas. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para problemas
  >   específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e
  >   técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software. Melhore a
  >   pergunta.
- > Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação.
  >   Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a
  >   outros usuários no futuro. Problemas assim podem ser evitados com a
  >   criação de um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

Comment: O problema maior da pergunta específica é que não  tem sequer uma definição do que o soft deveria fazer, além de revisar o código precisa de "engenharia reversa" pra saber o que ele faz, tampouco diz qual o aspecto da revisão esperada, ficou quase "baseada em opinião" além de ampla. Poderiam surgir infinitas respostas com códigos completamente diferentes e até incorretos da forma que está, pra piorar um pouco. E ainda, pode ser que o código não funcione, aí não seria uma garibada, seria um "termine pra mim", o que definitivamente não é função do site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu prefiro amplo, porque não tem um problema específico, mas tem um esforço, um código, pode ser útil para outras pessoas.

Eu acho que *off* é mais quando o problema é específico demais, sem esforço, quer que faça o código. Mas se achar melhor esse então seria o primeiro não tem erro de sintaxe e nem nada para reproduzir de erro (que é diferente não poder ser reproduzido conforme o que a pessoa informou, e é diferente de não ter informações suficiente para reproduzir que aí seria um problema de falta de clareza).

Há casos que dá para aceitar, desde que não seja tão amplo, se for só um trecho pequeno de código, se a pessoa disser o que especificamente o que ele quer que melhore, se ela vê alguma coisa que não parece certa apesar de funcionar.

É um caso complicado, eu não cravaria uma forma única de interpretar, por isso não fechei (e não estou dizendo que mereça ficar aberta). È o tal do [Gorila vs Tubarão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101).

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de pergunta não é aceita no StackOverflow EN porque já existe o CodeReview pra esse propósito (que também é em EN). Como não há um CodeReview PT, acredito que o StackOverflow PT pode absorver perguntas desse tipo. Elas geralmente dão bastante trabalho pra responder, mas é muito legal quando alguém experiente se dá o trabalho de analisar cada trecho do código e propor melhorias. É algo que ajuda não apenas o OP, mas sim todos que leem a resposta.

Considerando especificamente a pergunta linkada pelo OP, o defeito dela é não incluir a tag [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo).

Comment: Considerando que o assunto ficou extenso, movi a conversa [para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107799/discussion-on-answer-by-gabriel-qual-o-motivo-fechamento-para-quando-o-usuario-s), que é o mecanismo melhor para interagir nestes casos. Basta clicar no link para ler ou acrescentar algo.