# Política sobre perguntas de nível "RTFM"

Tags: debate, perguntas

Neste post, me refiro a perguntas (extremamente) amadoras do tipo "Como verificar se uma variável está declarada na linguagem X".

Este tipo de pergunta seria bem aceita no SOPT?

O meu lado Stack Overflowniano grita "**leia o bendito manual!** DV, CV", porém meu outro lado está ciente que:

- SOPT é uma comunidade em desenvolvimento, seu escopo ainda não deve ser tão estreito como do SO matriz;
- Estas perguntas de nível iniciante estão entre as mais procuradas no Google (o número absurdo de upvotes para estas perguntas no SO matriz é a prova disto). Se no recusarmos a responder estas perguntas, perderemos uma quantidade de tráfico enorme.

Então, acredito que não há problema desde que tais perguntas são sejam duplicatas. Ou, estas perguntas deveriam ser fechadas por falta de esforço de pesquisa de qualquer forma?

---

**Update:** como comentado por **@bigown**, esta questão é relacionada com [O que fazer com perguntas no estilo “Como fazer X?”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/105/1944), porém quero focar em um subgrupo destas questões mais específico. Apenas questões simples, com zero ou quase zero de esforço de pesquisa, mas que são bem populares no Google. Por exemplo, estas questões do SO em inglês:

- [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025282/1331430) -> [Dúvida sobre px, dp, dip and sp no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295/1944)
- [What is the maximum value for a int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94591/1331430)
- [How to remove a property from a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/208105/1331430)
- [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27509/1331430)
- [How do I trim a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/498970/1331430)
- [Java optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters)

Acredito que nenhuma destas perguntas seria bem aceita se postadas hoje no Stack Overflow em inglês, devido a simplicidade/falta de pesquisa. Estas questões seriam aceitas aqui? Se não forem bem aceitas devido a falta de pesquisa, faríamos vista grossa para dispormos mais conteúdo útil?

Embora as perguntas demonstrem praticamente zero de esforço, as respostas para as mesmas são úteis para uma grande parcela de usuários. Uma [resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19673/186879) no meta.SO (2009) ressalta isto (em tradução livre):

> > O usuário não tem a habilidade ou inclinação para perguntar para o onipotente Google?
>
> - Isto não é um problema aqui. Se a questão não está no SO e é relacionada a programação, é uma questão válida.
> - O objetivo é para que o resultado no topo do Google seja uma pergunta do SO.

... Porém, no último ano, o Stack Overflow em inglês tornou-se mais rigoroso quanto a falta de esforço por parte dos questionadores. Outro tópico (do meta.SO em inglês) mais recente sobre esforço: [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/186879) também aborda o problema do que julgamos de "esforço necessário". A resposta atualmente mais votada menciona que permitir perguntas sem nenhum esforço (sem nem mesmo procurar no google ou na documentação) aumentaria o problema do [*vampirismo de ajuda*](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)<sup>em inglês</sup>.

Parece cada vez mais difícil chegar a um consenso do que permitir aqui. Claro que questões que já possuem respostas de qualidade não devem ser deletadas (mesmo que suspensas, o conteúdo continua disponível).

Minha pergunta é: como devemos tratar futuras questões que não demonstram esforço algum? Podemos dividir em mais subgrupos:

- nenhum esforço e "muito localizado"/"difícil de compreender" (que dificilmente ajudaria visitantes futuros): suspender para evitar vampirismo.
- nenhum esforço mas que gera respostas de qualidade: estou em dúvida aqui, devemos fazer vista grossa para expandir o conteúdo e prover mais resultados no Google?

Comment: Não consigo dar um resposta decente agora, mas você disse quase tudo o que precisa ser pensado. Saiba mais em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x

Comment: @bigown é um tópico relacionado sim, porém vamos estreitar o escopo desta questão: referindo especificamente a questões sem nenhum esforço (pois qualquer esforço responderia) mas que também são extremamente "populares" no tio Google. Vou editar a questão com alguns exemplos para ilustrar.

Comment: @bigown atualizei a questão para deixar mais especifica, porém, após ler o tópico que você linkou e o post do meta.SO linkado a partir de lá, estou vendo que vai ser bem difícil (se não impossível) chegar a um consenso quanto a este tipo (relativamente) raro de pergunta que quero tratar aqui.

Comment: Nem tanto. Estou um pouco na correria agora para bolar algo legal para postar. Tem outras coisas relacionadas (não iguais): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/583/devemos-aceitar-perguntas-que-pedem-definicao-de-termos

Comment: @bigown sem problemas, também tenho que sair logo e se seguir digitando aqui meu cérebro vai explodir. Bom, como você disse na questão linkada, "o objetivo dos sites SE é ter uma das perguntas como primeiro link de qualquer busca do Google" isto significa então que devemos fazer vista grossa para questões que são procuradas com frequência independente do fator de esforço, eu assumo. Bom, podemos ver isso com mais calma mais tarde ou depois sem pressa.

Comment: Eu também gostaria de responder mas vou ter de esperar por falta de tempo... Só um ponto: tem muitos casos em que o "bendito manual" não existe em português.

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente, este é um ponto que eu não tinha levado em consideração. Seria bom tê-lo em uma resposta. `=]` Também tenho que sair, volto para verificar aqui em ~12 horas.

Comment: Precisamos depois criar uma FAQ p/ o q for decidido como ocorreu no SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions

Comment: A pior pergunta é a que não foi feita.

Comment: Essa tipo de pergunta é, até bem pontuada no SO, tirando alguns usuários que até hoje não entendem que existem pessoas começando e ninguém nasce sabendo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se não me engano, no SO existem perguntas bem desse nível RTFM, ou muito comuns.

O padrão adotado por lá é o seguinte: para perguntas que realmente são problema de preguiça por parte de quem a fez, é voto negativo, fechamento e algumas recomendações bem... Acaloradas... Sobre reforma de atitude. Como em geral essas perguntas são removidas depois de um tempo, não tenho um exemplo forte nem que vá perdurar. Vou dar meu próprio exemplo então:

"Qual é o código hexadecimal em HTML pra cor XYZ?"

Para dúvidas que são legítimas, para as quais a documentação é pobre ou insuficiente, a pergunta é mais do que bem vinda! O SO se torna a referência para a solução daquele problema. E a pergunta se torna um ponto para onde você pode apontar quando surgirem duplicatas.

[***Este é  maior exemplo de todos***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

O que diferencia um tipo de pergunta da outra? Em minha opinião, o bom-senso. Antes de votar  negativamente em uma pergunta, ou sinalizar ou pedir seu fechamento, **tente honestamente respondê-la**. Se você não for capaz de responder em uma frase curta nem puder indicar uma documentação direta, objetiva e oficial naquele momento, deixe a pergunta em paz. Se for algo pertinente, outros usuários com a mesma dúvida elevarão sua pontuação naturalmente (como parece estar acontecendo por aqui).

Comment: Fica claro que não devemos fechar. Se lá aceita, aqui tem mais motivo ainda para aceitar. Ainda vou pensar mais sobre o assunto mas acho que quem não gosta, deve ignorar. Claro que algo precisará ser feito e explodir de perguntas assim.

Comment: Nem sempre, bigowin. Já tive stacks fechados no SO com tanta velocidade que fiquei zonzo sem nem ter anotado a placa. É frustrante? Claro que é, mas é com punhos de ferro que o Stack Overflow é o que é e nunca vai ser o que não deve ser, outro fórum de TI supersaturado de sobrinhos remunerados pelo trabalho que nós, voluntários, fazemos por eles.

Comment: Mas pergunta citada em "Este é maior exemplo de todos" é muito aceitável primeiro, a ver pela data postada, em 2008 IE6 - IE9 ainda tiravam o sono de muitos devs, exceções que não estavam em Documentações e Tutoriais.