# Comparando a experiência do SO com o SOpt

Tags: debate, perguntas

Gostaria primeiramente de agradecer aos idealizadores do Stack em português, achei uma ótima idéia e tenho certeza que vai ajudar mais ainda os desenvolvedores do Brasil.

Vamos ao que interessa... E já sei que vou tomar muita tijolada por isso! Rsss...

Sou membro do Stack global a mais de 3 anos, possuo baixa reputação por lá (não estou sendo ironico), tenho reputação de 153, 1 medalha de prata e 13 de bronze, e coleciono 11 badges! E achei necessário expor meu ponto de vista e opnião sobre as "dúvidas" que vejo aqui no Stack "Brazuca".

Meu perfil: https://stackoverflow.com/users/575643/marcelo-filho

---

Como em todos os Stacks, há "dúvidas" e dúvidas sendo postadas todo o tempo, umas mais complexas e que realmente você não encontra nem na 15a página do Google, e outras que dá vontade de joga a mesa pro ar e mandar o usuário devolver o PC que comprou nas Casas Bahia.

Porém gostaria de sugerir que o mesmo incentivo e moderação seja aplicado aqui nesse Stack, digo, parar com o "mimimi" se uma pergunta é válida ou não. Todos nós sabemos, ao bater o olho, quando um usuário simplesmente postou por preguiça ou porque realmente trata-se de algo complexo e avançado. Por exemplo:

"Dúvida" 1: [Como usar MySQL em Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7763/como-usar-mysql-em-android)

"Dúvida" 2: [Utilizo PHP dentro de um HTML ou um HTML dentro de um PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7703/utilizo-php-dentro-de-um-html-ou-um-html-dentro-de-um-php)

Sério mesmo que isso não dava pra achar no Google? Mas se o cara não entendeu como o Android manipulado o SQLite num determinado processo ou o porque do módulo PHP no Apache só interpretar e entregar o PHP processado em arquivos .php e não em .html, é ooouuutra história.

Então nesse caso, ai de cima, seria legal já mandar o cara ir buscar no Google. Mas não como uma coisa ruim e ditatorial, mas sim como um incentivo de cultuar novos usuários/desenvolvedores a buscar até não aguentar mais antes de postar aqui, pra tornar a rede social mais produtiva e rica.

Há também os casos, ao meu ver, dos desenvolvedores que estão começando em algo novo e ainda não possuem muito conhecimento com as tecnologias que estão trabalhando, por exemplo a primeira dúvida abaixo:

Dúvida 1: [Evento onchange não funcionando quando colocado no body](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7750/evento-onchange-nao-funcionando-quando-colocado-no-body)

Dúvida 2: [Algoritmo de Breadcrumb em ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7823/algoritmo-de-breadcrumb-em-asp-net-mvc)

A primeira sim é uma dúvida, porém como eu comentei acima, é por pouco conhecimento na tecnologia, mas dá pra notar que o desenvolvedor já foi atrás e deu uma procurada. A 2a é ainda melhor, o developer criou uma solução, expos os possíveis problemas e pediu ajuda a comunidade! Essa sim é do c...!

Enfim...

Acho que a comunidade Brasileira poderia começar a se preocupar, no sentido amigável, em cultuar os novos usuários e desenvolvedores pesquisar o máximo possível antes de vir ao Stack. Para quando algum developer chegar aqui, encontrar as soluções para os problemas menos triviais possíveis.

Abraços.

=D

Comment: Na primeira vez fiz uma leitura superficial e demorei um bom tempo para entender o que era um stack global.. é o SO.com. Mas tem uma coisa que ainda não entendi, `Um “de para” do Stack global`, o que você quis dizer com isso? Não achei na pergunta. `de para` oq??

Comment: Não abandonei a pergunta @brasofilo, estou lendo e aceitando a opnião de todos sobre o que escrevi. Eu deveria debater com todos?! Rsss...

Comment: Mas podes explicar o que vem a ser ***de para***?? Isso deixa a pergunta bem confusa... acho que ninguém entendeu...

Comment: Claro: é uma expressão que siginifica comparar algo com outro, no caso, minha experiência com o Stack global (como eu defino o .com) e o português.

Comment: Então, o melhor seria um título tipo "Comparando a experiência do SO com o SOPT".

Comment: Acabo de ver uma infografia na teve mostrando um email e tinha lá "De: Para: Assunto:"... lembrei desta pergunta na hora... resolvi mudar o título da pergunta conforme meu comentário de meses atrás, não era nada claro.

Comment: +1 Por colocar a pergunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creio que a questão de um limiar para o quão simples as perguntas podem ser é algo que só pode ser definido pela experiência. De início, é melhor errar pra mais do que pra menos (i.e. na dúvida, aceitar a pergunta), só quando um determinado tipo de pergunta começar a ficar problemática por algum motivo é que se deve mudar a postura.

Como exemplo, veja essa pergunta do próprio Joel Spolsky no início do SOEN:

[How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)

"Como eu movo a tartaruga no LOGO?" Obviamente, não é uma dúvida de verdade, mas uma pergunta artificial para demonstrar [na época] a ideia de que não existe pergunta simples demais. Se for uma pergunta bem escrita e "respondível", ela teria lugar no site.

Só muito tempo depois (quase dois anos) é que se chegou a um consenso de que esse tipo de pergunta não era bem vinda no site, e o post foi fechado de vez. Por que não aprender com a experiência deles, então? Porque **copiar um comportamento** é diferente de **aprender**. Ok, você não precisa botar a mão no fogo pra se convencer que, de fato, queima, mas a menos que se existam boas razões para se acreditar que determinado tipo de pergunta é prejudicial à comunidade (e existem, no caso de perguntas subjetivas por exemplo) assumir que "se deu errado pra eles também vai dar pra gente" não me parece muito diferente de um ["culto à carga"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culto_%C3%A0_carga)...

Eu concordo com você que esse site não deve ser a **fonte primária** para alguém aprender programação. Eu não vejo alguém que sabe zero do assunto aprender tudo o que precisa "uma pergunta por vez". Apesar de concordar em maior parte com a [resposta do @Felipe Avelar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/973/215), algumas coisas simplesmente precisam ser aprendidas em outro lugar: noções básicas do que é um programa, como ele é criado a partir de um compilador, como funcionam instruções simples de atribuição, operações matemáticas, loops, etc. Em outras palavras, ter um "mínimo conhecimento do problema sendo resolvido" (motivo de fechamento no SOEN mas que [ainda] não existe aqui).

Se alguém não concorda, sugiro tentar fazer perguntas no nível da da tartaruga, e ver como a coisa se desenrola... Talvez eu esteja enganado, e se bem escritas essas perguntas tenham lugar aqui também. O maior cuidado que se precisa ter, na minha opinião, é para **não afastar os especialistas**: afinal, aqui é o lugar onde eu encontro boas respostas pra coisas que têm me quebrado a cabeça há anos (sério), não gostaria que se tornasse um lugar onde *somente* se pergunta/responde por coisas que poderiam ser achadas via RTFM (por mais *conveniente* que seja ter esse conhecimento aqui). Mas acredito que ambos podem coexistir em harmonia, pelo menos é o que tem se observado na prática...

Answer (score 9):

Possivelmente porque o **intuito** do site é ter resposta pra **todas** as possíveis perguntas. Por mais que se negative a questão por [falta de esforço para pesquisar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x), é importantíssimo, na minha opinião, que a comunidade forneça respostas para **quase** toda e qualquer dúvida que apareça e esteja dentro do escopo do SO.

Portanto, acho **extremamente** inadequado *aconselhar* usuários procurarem em outro lugar as respostas que nós podemos fonercer, além de ser uma atitude muito antipática e que **tende a afastar** possíveis membros da comunidade. Para isso é utilizado o sistema de votação, para dizer algo do tipo: "Nós estamos respondendo a sua dúvida, mas você poderia ter se esforçado mais antes de perguntar".

Comment: +1, e não só isso - como o objetivo é que o site tenha respostas para todas as possíveis perguntas, ao procurar no Google ele encontraria... um post aqui. Então a melhor solução seria indicar como pergunta repetida, ou responder caso não exista uma resposta anterior válida.

Answer (score 6):

Complementando as respostas de [mgibsonbr](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/977/201) e [Felipe Avelar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/973/201).

A rede Stack Exchange precisa de um equilíbrio entre *especialistas e entusiastas* que dedicam seu tempo livre a prover excelente conteúdo e *visibilidade e tráfico* que façam seus sites uma referência na rede global.

Quando um dos sites da Area 51 é promovido a Beta, precisa encontrar seu público e seus usuários fiéis até chegar a maturidade de *Full Member*. Acredito que a intenção primeira é que quando alguém digitar no Google:

> Como usar MySQL em Android

o primeiro resultado seja do SOPT.
Quando este site alcançar milhares e milhares de perguntas e MySQL+Android seja a duplicata da duplicata, então sim é hora de aplicar muito mais rigor nos votos e nos fechamentos de questões. Inclusive agora é a hora de aproveitar e escrever respostas canônicas pra essas "perguntas simples" que terão centenas de votos dentro de 3 anos.

Quanto à:

> Para quando algum developer chegar aqui, encontrar as soluções para os problemas menos triviais possíveis.

Acho que não, acho que é: *encontrar as soluções para **todos os problemas** possíveis* <sup>*****</sup>.
E, claro que isso é impossível, então é uma tarefa infinita. Ao trabalho então ;)

<sup>***** Conforme definido na Central de Ajuda</sup>

Comment: +1 concordo plenamente