# Perguntas sucintas ou contextuais?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Olá, a minha duvida é simples, eu procuro deixar minhas perguntas sucintas, sem muitas delongas já que nem sempre tenho muito tempo, porem me deparo muitas vezes com comentários de "sua pergunta está muito vaga", eu entendo que nem sempre fecho alguns pontos, mas são pontos de fácil dedução.

O que pensam sobre?

Fazer a pergunta mais extensa, cheia de detalhes, ou ser mais sucinto e deixar quem quiser responder pensar um pouco mais?

Answer (score 11):

Nada errado com perguntas sucintas. Se as pessoas não entendem o que deseja, ela não é sucinta, ela é vaga.

Se a pergunta não está clara ou ampla, ou seja não tem informações suficientes, ela deve ser fechada. Eventualmente até negativada porque falta esforço em fazer uma pergunta condizente e que possa ser respondida. Claro que antes é sempre bom tentar salvar. Ms aparentemente é sua decisão fazer algo "sucinto" e não que não conseguiu fazer melhor. Então sugiro fazer melhor logo de início, e se é capaz de fazer melhor, ajuda não é necessária.

Deixar a pergunta ambígua não é nada bom. Se pode deixar ela no ponto certo é sempre melhor. Deduções podem ser erradas.

Não precisa ser cheia de detalhes, até porque encher linguiça também é ruim, precisa ter os necessários.

Não vi todas, mas boa parte das suas perguntas precisam de um debate antes de responder, e não é o objetivo aqui, é para você colocar tudo o que precisa na pergunta. O objetivo sempre foi esse.

Idealmente os comentários nunca deveriam ser usados. Quando eles aparecem é porque tem algo errado. Claro que é aceitável que tenha essa falha, mas é melhor que eles não sejam usados.

Tem pergunta sua que só você consegue responder porque só você tem todos os detalhes. Boa parte das suas perguntas funcionam como em fórum, você lança alguma coisa, fica todo mundo tentando entender o que é, te dá dicas, e aí você consegue resolver, mas ninguém mais conseguira, não vai ajudar outra pessoa. Está longe do ideal. Tem pergunta que tem uma resposta, mas ela não parece te agradar, e a culpa talvez seja da pergunta não estar boa.

Eu fecharia boa parte das suas perguntas.

Eu acho até mesmo um acinte pedir ajuda e jogar a responsabilidade para quem for ajudar se virar para fazer esse favor. O respondedor deve se esforçar em dar uma boa resposta para uma boa pergunta.

Outras pessoas talvez pensem diferente e até por isso eu evito fazer algo. Eu sei que muito do site acabou virando um fórum, o que eu não gosto, mas não vou impor o que eu gosto.

Comment: Acontece que se eu for contextualizar todo o meu projeto, demandaria uma página gingante de pergunta, que muitas vezes se resolve em três ou quatro comentários.

Comment: Claro, meu objetivo é mudar minha visão, por isso fiz essa pergunta. Você acha mais viável uma pergunta maior que acaba ficando especifica? Ou um pergunta mais generalizada dando espaço para outras pessoas aprenderem?

Comment: Se resolve em comentários está errado. Se precisa de uma página gigante está errado. Precisa ser sucinto, mas não vago. Você acha que só pode ser gigante ou vago. Eu gosto mais das perguntas genéricas que todos aprendem, mas elas precisam ser de fato genéricas, e não amplas. Não é perguntar ["como faço x?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/105/101) pura e simplesmente. Genérica ou não, tem que dar para responder adequadamente. Sua perguntas costumam ser bem específicas, tanto que só você consegue respondê-las (generalizando).

Comment: Darei um exemplo, nessa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195505/71024, eu editei ela algumas vezes, mas inicialmente era colocar senha no projeto via VBA, porém, eu tentei ser claro no que queria, sem ter que demonstrar o contexto que estava trabalhando. Que demandaria um código bem extenso e uma pergunta não muito agradável pra uma duvida simples.

Answer (score 9):

Temos que deixar claro que sucinta é diferente de vaga. Uma pergunta sucinta será, sim, mais compacta, mas isso não implica em omitir detalhes, pois será pequena porque consegue ir direto ao assunto. Por sua vez, uma pergunta vaga também é compacta, mas faz isso omitindo detalhes importantes. Se você mesmo assume que tais perguntas possuem "pontos de fácil dedução", então claramente a sua pergunta é vaga, não sucinta. A questão de dedução aqui sempre é um problema, pois podem gerar soluções/respostas que não atendem a necessidade inicial porque o usuário deduziu de forma errada sobre os pontos omitidos. É bem comum você encontrar perguntas vagas com respostas completas e o autor da pergunta comentar: "já tentei isso, não funcionou". Não digo que seria o seu caso, mas ao omitir alguns detalhes que podem ser importantes, está abrindo brecha para que isso aconteça. Um usuário pouco mais experiente vai identificar isso com mais facilidade e possivelmente comentar que a pergunta está vaga e precisa ser completada com tais detalhes antes mesmo de responder, de fato, a pergunta.

Perguntas muito longas também são muito difíceis de compreender (exceto quando o contexto do problema demanda muito conteúdo). Eu particularmente voto como "Não está clara suficiente" em perguntas com muito código que não vejo a necessidade de tê-los, pois parece que o autor simplesmente os jogou ali e "se virem para achar o meu erro".

**Resumindo**: perguntas sucintas são legais. Perguntas curtas e vagas não são legais. Perguntas muito longas as vezes são legais, mas quase sempre não.

Answer (score 6):

A meu ver existem dois tipos de perguntas:

- Perguntas teóricas (i.e.: por que não é possível gerar números realmente aleatórios?, utilizar técnica X é uma má prática? etc.);
- Perguntas práticas.

Para evitar uma pergunta vaga com o primeiro tipo, basta indicar o tipo de situação no qual você deseja aplicar alguma técnica ou recurso.

Já para o segundo tipo, você deve sempre fornecer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel). Isso é necessário porque:

- Se o exemplo não for mínimo, a pergunta possui ruído que leva a perda de tempo de quem for tentar responder. Lembrando que mínimo não é o mesmo que o menor possível - claridade é essencial;
- Se o exemplo não for completo, a pergunta não será viável até ser editada tantas vezes quantas sejam necessário para que faça sentido;
- Se o exemplo não for verificável, então qualquer resposta é uma tentativa de adivinhação.

Siga as recomendações do link acima e suas perguntas nunca mais serão chamadas de vagas.